# Obtener registros coincidentes entre tablas de 2 origenes de datos

Tags: php

Tengo que crear una función PHP para listar los registros coincidentes por el campo ID_EMPLEADO , entre 2 tablas .

La tabla 1 es de Oracle , y solo tengo acceso a consultarla, se compone de todos los empleados que ingresan o estan presentes, se llena y vacía sola en tiempo real, yo solo puedo acceder mediante una consulta que me pasaron.

La tabla 2 la hice en Mysql, tengo acceso total a modificar y eliminar, y alli tengo cargados a todos los empleados, pero solo 2 campos ID_EMPLEADO y "Avisar", este ultimo por defecto con valor cero. La idea sería poder marcar ( valor 1 en campo Avisar ) los empleados que quiero saber que ingresaron.

Necesito comparar ambas tablas, cada 2 minutos, y mostrar un aviso en pantalla cuando cualquier ID de la tabla 2 con el campo avisar en 1 , aparezca activo en la Tabla 1 ( tabla donde solo estan los que ingresaron ).
Abajo copio como obtengo los registros de la tabla 1 (Oracle) desde mi php.

```html
<?php
    function empleados_actuales($conn)
    {
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT ID_EMPLEADO FROM TABLE(Ver_Empleados.Obtener_empleados()) ORDER BY ID_EMPLEADO");
        if (!$stid) {
            $e = oci_error($conn);
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        $r = oci_execute($stid);
        if (!$r) {
            $e = oci_error($stid);
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        return $stid;
    }
?>
```

No soy muy avanzado en PHP pero estoy intentando aprender, no se como comparar datos de una consulta Oracle, con datos de una consulta en Mysql. Podrian ayudarme a armar como hacerlo, aunque sea básicamente ?

Comment: No me había dado cuenta, pero puedo traer los registros desde oracle a mysql , cada 2 minutos , y llenar una tabla temporal , para tener todo en mysql .